# Pinescript - how do you call the commission variable/ input to use in your script?

Tags: pine-script

Pinescript - how do you call the commission variable/ input to use in your script?
I'd like to be able to use it in determining limit prices etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's what you need:

```
//@version=5
compercVal  = 10
strategy("My Strategy", commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = compercVal)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

except you cannot use input variable for `compercVal`, because `strategy()` function parameters should have constant arguments.

Comment: brilliant, thought I'd never get there with that one